# How to check application present in other mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am having two mobile in both mobile i having my x application i want to check using blutooth  to applcation is presnt or not in other mobile how I check applcation is presnt in othe mobile using phonegap any plugin is available fot this???

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you have control to public a some kind of Url in the destination app. Sometimes is already done like Facebook, Twitter, but you have to review every case in particular

A lot of IOS apps have a Custom Url scheme that you can launch from your App.

Further reading: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Current of Custom Url schemes: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

Android does a similar way through Public intents filters more flexible, you can attend Send commands:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: Any plugin is available for PeerFinder in android??